# How to fetch from a database for consistent pagination of "newest" items while more items are being inserted

Tags: php, ajax, web, pagination, load

Let's say I have a database where I am storing user posts in a table 'posts'.
Now, I have a page where I show posts from all users. Newest posts are shown first.

```
------------------------
id   |  details |  time
------------------------
21    |  some21   |  10pm
------------------------
20    |  some20   |  9pm
------------------------
19    |  some19   |  8pm
------------------------
++++++++++++++++++++++++
------------------------
 1    |  some1   |  1pm
------------------------
```

I retrieve 10 posts at a time and show it on the page using AJAX. Next time, I send an AJAX request to skip the first 10 results and load the 10 after that. And so on.

A problem arises when there are new entries to 'posts' table.

---

```
id   |  details |  time
------------------------
31    |  some31   |  10pm
------------------------
30    |  some30   |  10pm
------------------------
29    |  some29   |  10pm
------------------------
++++++++++++++++++++++++
------------------------
 1    |  some1   |  1pm
------------------------
```

Now, when the AJAX request goes with some skip number, it will skip new entries and load same results which were already shown.

How can I prevent loading some results on the page that were already shown on a previous page?

Answer (score 0):

New entries have a new `id`, and you access them in descending order. Now when you request for page `2` you can also send the id of last element in current list such that this page will fetch top 10 elements with id less that this one.